# Run button missing for c# in VSCODE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When I am using python in Visual Studio Code, I have the run button at the top right, however, when I am in a c# file, the run button is not there.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a run profile for that workspace

Comment: What is a run profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since VS Code is a tool built with C# in mind, having the Run hidden is not a disadvantage but rather to dedicate a complete UI for Running and Debugging your C# code. The Run and Debug UI which you can access from the left menu gives your this capability with comprehensive tools to help you debug.

Activating this tool to run correctly involves two setups, one-time setup and a per-project setup **(Don't let this intimidate you, it is just a click of a button)**

### First Time Setup

**1. Install .NET command line tools**
Install the .NET Core command line tools (CLI) by following the installation part of the instructions here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

**2. Install C# Extension for VS Code**
In the extensions tab, enter C# in the search box and press Enter. Select the extension from Microsoft and click on Install. If you have previously installed the C# extension, make sure that you have a recent version.

**3. Wait for download of platform-specific files**
The first time that C# code is opened in VS Code, the extension will download the platform-specific files needed for debugging and editing. Debugging and editor features will not work until these steps finish.

### Once Per Project

**1. Get a project**
You can start from scratch by creating an empty console project with `dotnet new`. Begin by opening the terminal in Visual Studio Code (View->Integrated Terminal) or CTRL+` and type these commands:

```
cd ~
mkdir MyApplication
cd MyApplication
dotnet new console
```

**2. Open the directory in VS Code**
Go to File->Open Folder (File->Open on macOS) and open the directory in Visual Studio Code. If this is the first time that the C# extension has been activated, it will now download additional platform-specific dependencies.

**3. Add VS Code configuration files to the workspace**
VS Code needs to be configured so it understands how to build your project and debug it. For this there are two files which need to be added -- .vscode/tasks.json and .vscode/launch.json.

- Tasks.json is used to configure what command line command is executed to build your project, and launch.json configures the type of debugger you want to use, and what program should be run under that debugger.
- Launch.json configures VS Code to run the build task from tasks.json so that your program is automatically up-to-date each time you go to debug it.

If you open the folder containing your project, the C# extension can automatically generate these files for you if you have a basic project. When you open a project and the C# extension is installed, you should see the following prompt in VS Code:

[image: VSCode C# Prompt]

> Clicking Yes when you see this prompt is all that you really have to do when you open a new dotnet project. If the files are there already you won't be prompted.

Clicking Yes on this prompt should add these resources. Should you need to add those resources manually please check the reference link below.

**4. Start debugging**
Your project is now all set. Set a breakpoint or two where you want to stop, click the debugger play button (or press F5) and you are off.

[image]

Reference Link: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md

Answer (score -2):

try pressing f5, should do the same thing as the run button